# Procedure to to make a Login System in Code Igniter 4 with JWT

Tags: api, rest, jwt

I want to create a Rest API + JWT based login module in Code Igniter 4

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the following [Link](https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-secured-restful-api-codeigniter-php). In this blog, they also developed the same thing which you asked for.

Comment: Thank you very much . I will follow it . However is there any blogs or help documents that handles the client side/view request/response also? Here i do see that we have to use postman